# SQL DB time validation against current

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying out below where I intend to validate the time that a temporary password stays live in a mySQL database.

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "Sales");
$q = "SELECT TB_TOKENTEMP FROM TBUSER WHERE TB_FNAME='mango'";
$qu = mysqli_query($conn, $q);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($qu, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Colombo');
    $DBTime = $row['TB_TOKENTEMP'];
    $DBtimeconverted = strtotime($DBTime);
    $Curtime = time();
    $newtime = $Curtime-$DBtimeconverted;
    if(($Curtime-$DBtimeconverted) > 1800) //1800 seconds (half and hour)
    {     
        echo "Half an hour gone and your password is expired. <br>";
        echo "Here's the time since the password is generated : " . round($newtime/3600)." Hour(s) ".($newtime/60)." Minutes ".($newtime%60)." seconds<br>";
    }
        else 
    {
        echo "Password token still valid.";
    }

}
$conn->close();
?>
```

The code works as is, however I'm struggling with two things;

**1.** The out put I get once the desired time lapses looks like this.

> Half an hour gone and your password is expired.
>   Here's the time since the password is generated : 0 Hours 0.66666666666667 Minutes 40 seconds

and as the time lapses further, it looks like this.

> Half an hour gone and your password is expired  Here's the time since
>   the password is generated : 0 Hour(s) 13.5 Minutes 30 seconds

Point here is that I see decimal points added to the minutes calculation which I want to be removed. (I'm not sure when the hours goes by, the same will happen to the hours too)

**2.** Second questions is that now that I've set the default time zone to Asia/Colombo, the validation happens against that. If a user is locating in a different time zone, this validation wouldn't probably stand. Is there a way that `date_default_timezone_set()` can be generalized so it validates against a user specific time zone?

3. Is there a better way I can handle the same thing with SQL?